# "Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set" error for Offset function

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a "problem" where I need to use VBA, otherwise I would have used excel formulas.

I am looking up a Max of a column, to each column is a corresponding name for that entry. I'd like to pull the max of the column and populate into cells (2, 17) and populate with the corresponding name in cells(2, 16). Hope that makes sense. Here is that section in my script (the final line is where i am getting my error):

```
Dim max As Double
        max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range("k:k"))
        'values column defined above
        Cells(2, 17) = max

   Dim maxn As Variant
       Set maxn = Range("K:K").Find(max, lookat:=xlWhole)
        'name column as defined above offset by number of columns to the name column
        Cells(2, 16) = maxn.Offset(0, -2)
```

I've attempted to define maxn in different ways (Strings and long) but i've read that "offset function" is a variant type so I have stayed with that.
I've attempted "Set maxn =..." "Let maxn = ..." and "maxn = ..." all get the same error.

This error and other thread's i've read made me think that it is looking at the cells before they have been populated, thus giving me an error. So I've re-ordered the code to have the offsets at the very bottom of my code (since VBA is linear in it's execution). I still get the same error.

Comment: It will error in vbscript due to using named parameters. But you've tagged VBS and VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution, after watching the Macro stop in action. It would populate my min and max in the spreadsheet with zero's and the columns it was searching through did not get a chance to populate.

Although (from what i read) VBA is supposed to run line by line. It was not. To ensure that code had a chance to run before my max and min ran, I put it in a separate sub, and the original sub utilized a Call.

```
Sub originalsub()
{code}
call maxsub
end sub

sub maxsub()
{code}
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need anything so complicated. This works fine for me:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Cells.Clear

For i = 1 To 10
 Cells(i, 9) = i
 Cells(i, 11) = Rnd
Next i

Dim max As Double
max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range("k:k"))
Cells(2, 6) = max

Dim maxn As Variant
Set maxn = Range("K:K").Find(max, lookat:=xlWhole)
Cells(2, 5) = maxn.Offset(0, -2)

End Sub
```

Comment: the issue with that, was that it was looking for the max in row K before it was populated, and then pulling from cells (2,6) for the reference of max, before there was anything populated there, creating the error91 . Glad to see my initial coding thought was on the right path though